# How do I deal with riots?

Tags: civilization-2

Lately I have been replaying Civ 2 and there seems to be a constant problem in my cities, namely riots. I know that too much trade and not enough entertainers can cause riots. However, when I convert one of my citizens to a entertainer there is always a famine. What improvements are there that will make citizens happy/ improvements that will allow for more food production from each food square (can you put them in list form)?

Comment: There are a large number of unhappiness-increasing buildings. You can also modify your tax rate to have a higher percentage go to Luxuries.

Comment: examples of unhappiness-increasing buildings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happiness inducing buildings include the following:

Temple, Cathedral, Colosseum

Hanging Gardens, Oracle, Michelangelo's Chapel, Shakespeare's Theater, Bach's Cathedral, Cure for Cancer

Other things that generate happiness are Luxury tax rate, and garrisoned units.

Things that generate unhappiness include Distance from Palace (mitigated by courthouse), Number of Cities (Despotism), Troops away from cities (mitigated by police station), Ongoing War, City Size.

Special Note: Under Fundamentalism, your citizens are NEVER unhappy.

Comment: Another way of reducing unhappiness: reduce the size of the city. There is a special happiness penalty over a certain size.

Comment: what is a garrisoned unit?

Comment: @Johann A military unit in the same hex as a city, usually fortified. It gets a defensive bonus from the city, and reduces unhappiness of the citizens therein, with differing effectiveness in the various governments.